# Is this the right way to pass data to a stateful component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I've been learning ReactJS. On its documentation, it is recommended to use setState method to make any changes on the component but also in the documentation, it is not recommended to rely on "props" because the "state" and "props" work asynchronously.

`Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.`

The example below is from the documentation but a counter hasn't been implemented to the example so I made it by myself. *I wonder is the method below the right way to pass data to a stateful component and change its data after it has been created.*

```
class Clock extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {date:new Date(),counter:parseInt(this.props.counter)};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.tick(),
        1000);
    }

    componentDidUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    tick(){

        this.setState((prevState,props)=>({
            date:new Date(),
            counter:prevState.counter+1 
        }));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()} - {this.state.counter}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<div><Clock counter="0" /><Clock counter="10" /></div>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

An attribute named "counter" is passed to the component, then it is added to the "state" on the constructor and after that, the state takes responsibility for changing its data.

The thing I don't understand that isn't the "props" responsible for data? Is my method true and recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that you are not doing anything wrong. The docs says that you should not rely on `this.props` and `this.state` to compute the next `state`. And in fact you are avoiding that updating the state as a function of the previous state:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  date: new Date(),
  counter: prevState.counter + 1 
}));
```

this is the right way to do it, while this other way is NOT the right way:

```
this.setState({
  date: new Date(),
  counter: this.state.counter + 1 
});
```

at least for the case where your future state depends on the previous one. You are also using the props correctly to initiate the component, so you are passing down data that you want to use to initialize the state of your component. Which is totally fine. After that the state takes charge and alters the state based on the tick function.